# Multiple computer communication - multiprocessing.Listener, ensure port remains available?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

The use case for this is I need my server to open up a socket for communication upon receiving a valid message at an endpoint (this will be done via Proxys and multiprocessing.Managers). The endpoint returns what port the client should attempt to connect to. And allows the server to spawn a subprocess/subthread that will handle that specific task while allowing additional request to come in at the endpoint.

The problem comes from the fact that in order to get a free port I have to attach a socket to ('localhost', 0) as the address on the server side, and therefore the port is not open to clients. I can do this, make note of the port, and reopen the port using the local/public ip, however, there is no guarantee that another process did not grab that port immediately after closing the localhost socket. Correct?

Here is my attempt, and it works; however, it does not account for the fact that the port can be claimed before my script reclaims it using a public/local ip.

Is this acceptable or is there a better way to handle this? Under what conditions could I expect the port to be claimed before my code reclaimed it?

#### Client

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client

address = ('192.168.1.68', 50000)

def client():
    #Get port from endpoint
    conn = Client(address, authkey=b'secret password')
    port = conn.recv()
    conn.close()

    #Connect to port
    conn = Client((address[0], int(port)), authkey=b'secret password') #Connects to open port

    #Wait for task to complete
    delay = conn.recv()
    print(f'Task took {delay} seconds.')
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

#### Server

```
import time
import random
import socket
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client
from threading import Thread

def get_local_ip():
  return socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def get_free_port():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
    s.bind(('localhost', 0))
    port = s.getsockname()[1]
    s.close()
    return port

def socket_specific_task(port,):
    """
        Perform a task asynchonously after receiving a connection on the 
        specified port
    """
    address = (get_local_ip(), port)
    listener = Listener(address, authkey=b'secret password')
    print('Listening on', listener.address)
    conn = listener.accept()
    print('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)

    delay = random.randint(1,3)
    time.sleep(delay)

    conn.send(str(delay))
    
    conn.close()
    listener.close()

def server():
    address = (get_local_ip(), 50000) #Endpoint located on port 50000
    listener = Listener(address, authkey=b'secret password')
    print('Listening on', listener.address)
    conn = listener.accept()
    print('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)

    port = get_free_port() ##### Port not guarenteed to remain open after this line #####

    #Asynchonously perform task and respond to connections on the free port
    thread = Thread(
        target=socket_specific_task,
        args=(port,)
    )
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    
    conn.send(str(port)) #Send back port to expect results to come from
    
    thread.join()
    conn.close()
    listener.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

Comment: That's a terrible design. A server should be reachable on a well-known port. And you already have this working on port 50000. Also, don't use a port in the ephemeral port range (>32768 on Linux) for a long-lived port.

Comment: @rveerd This is not a publicly available server. It is intended for short lived intranet cluster computing. Driver code needs proxies they can poll, without having to send a packet to the server - Im doing this by creating sockets to monitor on the clients. The server doesnt need to be bothered 1000 times a second, from each client, from 300+ different clients. What is an alternative design that can accomplish this if you think this one is so terrible?

Comment: Your port 50000 is a long-lived port that you listen on.

Comment: Accepting a connection already creates a new socket for the communication between the client and the server. You can handle this socket/communication in separate thread. There is no need to setup a second connection.